# Scrolling character letter in C++

Tags: c++

I am building a part of a tower defense game in a strictly console environment and i am stuck at the moving of a creature lets say "c", i would like the letter "c" to start on the left and move a space at a time to the right on the same line basically:

> c (one second later)
>
> > ```
> > c (one second later)
> > ```
> >
> > > ```
> > > c and so on....
> > > ```

i thought that this could be implimented with an array but am lost, i want to be able to use simple code, not weird libraries and weird methods, just simple as possible. Thank you

Comment: Using [string streams with padding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667183/padding-stl-strings-in-c) should do the trick, unless that counts as "weird libraries and weird methods".

Comment: Updating the terminal output is a non-trivial task that depends on the terminal you are using. I am fairly certain the simplest way to do this is using a "weird" library such as [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29)

Comment: yes that would work but is there a way to loop it so it continuously moves? what i mean is say i have 10 creatures so 10 "c"s i need them to appear one after another and then go off the screen

Comment: If you're not on Windows, you can make your own weird library with weird methods that implement [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to move the cursor around.  If you are on Windows, you can make your own weird library with weird methods that use the [console API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682087.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

One method is display all the characters, then a carriage return ('\r') and then reprint the line.
This allows you to "walk" characters across.  **This will only work on video terminals that do not advance a line upon receiving a CR.**

Another method would be to print 10 backspace characters, a space, then your 10 'c'.  This may not be as fast as the carriage return method above, but worth looking at.

As others have said, you may want to look into a terminal library such as *ncurses*.  The library allows you to position the cursor on the screen, based on the terminal type.  This may require setting up the console window to emulate a terminal.